# I've set the classpath for tomcat for servlet but my program has cannot find symbol error please give me solution

Tags: java

```
symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
  location: class New_User

New_User.java:12:
 error: cannot find symbol
      public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
symbol:   class ServletException
  location: class New_User

New_User.java:2: 
error: package javax.servlet does not exist
 import javax.servlet.*;

New_User.java:3:
 error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
 import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

Comment: Please add your whole project setup here so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven add the below code. It seems library  is missing

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```